# Avoid that Vue autotriggers onclick method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have been working around a span that is generated by Vue´s (version 2.2) method, and my problem is that, when the span is created, the method inside onclick is automatically launched. So, I'm looking for a way to avoid this behaviour and make this span only clickable by the user.

```
fnLikeIcon(colName, rowData) {
                let currentStatus = '';
                if (rowData.isLike) {
                    currentStatus = `<span class="mdi mdi-ok" onclick=${this.changeFavouriteProperty(colName, rowData)}"></span>`;
                } else {
                    currentStatus = `<span class="mdi mdi-outline" onclick=${this.changeLikeProperty(colName, rowData)}"></span>`;
                }
                return currentStatus;
            }
```

This above methods, calls this other one.

```
changeLikeProperty(colName, rowData) {
                if (rowData.isLike) {
                    this.unmarkAsLike(rowData);
                } else {
                    this.markAsLike(rowData);
                }
            }
```

I tried with .prevent() after onclick, but really I'm not sure why this behaviour happens. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you actually run the function while generating the string for your span. And you bind to `onclick` the result of that function, not the function itself.
Wrap it withing an anonymous function and you're good!

```
fnLikeIcon(colName, rowData) {
   let currentStatus = '';
   if (rowData.isLike) {
    currentStatus = `<span class="mdi mdi-ok" onclick=${() => this.changeFavouriteProperty(colName, rowData)}"></span>`;
   } else {
    currentStatus = `<span class="mdi mdi-outline" onclick=${() => this.changeLikeProperty(colName, rowData)}"></span>`;
   }
 return currentStatus;
}
```

Note: I'm not sure why you create your elements like this, I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do (using dynamic bindings on a vue template or a render function)

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation. Really, I take this way because at this moment I have not a lot of experiencie with Vue, but the approach you speak about looks better.

Comment: @Jonan87 If you need help with Vue, feel free to join the official Vue discord (https://discord.gg/vue). Good luck with your learning!